# django tests setUp and --keepdb

Tags: django, django-testing

I have many, many migrations I can't delete. So when I run the tests it takes too much time unless I run them with `--keepdb` which is perfect. The only question is how does `--keepdb` and the `setUp` method work together. In the `setUp` method of the test I do something like this:

```
class APITests(APITestCase):

    fixtures = ['tests/testdata.json']

    def setUp(self):
        username = "test"
        password = "1234"

        user_created = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)

        body = {
            "username": username,
            "password": password
        }

        cart = Cart.objects.create()
        Client.objects.create(user=user_created, cart=cart)
```

`APITestCase` is just a django rest framework wrapper for the django test class. I create a user, a client and a cart for that user. If I re-run the tests with `--keepdb`, will the `setUp` method create a duplicated user or cart? how does it work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setUp method runs before every test case in your `APITests`. Because each test runs in a transaction, any objects created are destroyed at the end of each test.

The `keepdb` option does not affect this at all.

You might be able to use [`setupTestData`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) to make your tests more efficient.